# On Android the statusbar and the navigation bar are still visible while the splashscreen is showing. How to get rid of it?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, fullscreen, splash-screen

This is a weird problem with Apache Cordova.
I've set up an application to be packaged for Android. Since Android 4.4 there's the immersive mode.
So when I add:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

to **config.xml** and start the application, I can see the status bar going out of the screen to the top and the navigation bar gets out of the screen to the bottom - as expected.

As soon as I utilize Cordova's splashscreen plugin using:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

and add a splashscreen to config.xml like so:

```
<splash src="res/screen/android/splashScreen.png" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
```

things are a little different.

During the time the splashscreen is visible, the screen looks like this:

[image: Screenshot showing splashscreen]

As you can see, the navigation and status bar are still visible.
Well, as soon as the splashscreen disappears, I can see the status/navigation bar moving out of the screen - thus it looks like now it's switching to immersive mode.
Unfortunately this messes up the layout of the application. It seems like the actual application is now put in-between the area, where the status bar and the navigation bar have been. So instead of something fullscreen I have black borders at the top and the bottom.
This looks a little something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the application]

Obviously Android returns the wrong screen dimensions because the status and the navigation bar were still there. How can I force Cordova to switch to immersive mode as soon as the splashscreen is on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Question: does cordova have uses the Android native's styles and Manifest(pretty sure it does)? If so you can:

Use a full screen theme/style on your activity.

On your styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and then use it in Manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this ain't working. The compiler moans:

**cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.domain.test:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed linking references.**

because apparently it can't fine the 'base' theme.

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml files?

Comment: I'd love to but I don't know how. I'm no allowed to write more than 600 characters.

Comment: I've raised another question because this is a little out-of-topic here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573276/cordova-fails-to-find-theme-appcompat-light

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this?